# TypeORM: Select where relation property equals to x

Tags: node.js, typeorm

It seems that `TypeORM` relation select condition only allows `ID`. I want to do where clause where relation property equals to `x`.

Example:

These are the entity:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;
  
  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;
  
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  phone: string;

  @Column({ type: "nvarchar", length: "MAX", nullable: true })
  thumbnail: string;

  @Column({ type: "nvarchar", length: "MAX", nullable: true })
  token: string | null;

  @OneToMany(
    (type) => ChatRoomParticipant,
    (chatRoomParticipant) => chatRoomParticipant.user
  )
  participants: ChatRoomParticipant[];

  @ManyToOne(
    (type) => Application,
    (application) => application.users
  )
  application: Application;
}

@Entity()
export class Application {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column({type: "nvarchar", length: "MAX", nullable: true})
    token: string | null;

    @Column("bigint")
    dateCreated: number;

    @Column()
    status: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Owner, owner => owner.applications)
    owner: Owner;

    @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.application)
    users: User[];
}
```

I want to select the `count` of user which assigned in an application.

```
let count = await userRepo
    .createQueryBuilder("user")
    .where(
      "user.username = :username AND user.application.token = :applicationToken"
    )
    .setParameters({
      username: model.username,
      applicationToken: model.applicationToken,
    })
    .getCount()
```

This gives me error:

> Error: Cannot call methods on nvarchar.

If I change `applicationToken` into `applicationId` then it works:

```
let count = await userRepo
  .createQueryBuilder("user")
  .where("user.username = :username AND user.application = :applicationId")
  .setParameters({
    username: model.username,
    applicationId: "afb3015e-be49-ec11-ae4d-74d83e04f9d3",
  })
  .getCount();
```

How to compare the relation using other prop than id?

Comment: ```username``` is ```unique```. Your query returns either ```0``` or ```1``` since there can be only 1 user with the specified username.
Moreover, do you want that a ```user``` can have more than 1 application??? From your model a user can have at maximum 1 application.

Comment: In ```User``` change ```thumbnail: string;``` to ```thumbnail?: string;``` and ```token: string | null;``` to ```token?: string;```. In ```Application``` change ```token: string | null;``` to ```token?: string;```

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
.leftJoinAndSelect("user.application", "app")
.where("user.username = :username", { username: model.username })
.andWhere("app.token = :token", { token: model.applicationToken })
.getCount();
```

Just use leftJoinAndSelect? You can join with the `application` table, alias it as `app`, then access it as `app.token = :token`.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md)